# angular material md-button ng-click doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

md-button with ng-click doesn't work.
So I created simple controller like following.
Wen I clicked button2 its works, but click md-button nothing happening.

**controller**

```
app.controller('MyContrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        $scope.message = "asdfa";
    };
});
```

**html**

```
{{message}}
<md-input-container>
    <md-button ng-click="sumit()">Button1 - Doesn't work</md-button>
</md-input-container>
<button ng-click="submit()" value="Button2- works" class="md-raised">sdf</button>
```

Comment: I see you spelled wrongly for the first button.  ng-click="sumit()"

Comment: @Karthik Good catch. If it is a typo we can close it.. :)

Comment: i'm disappointed myself ask this question.. You're right, just typo...

Answer (score 10):

You have a typo on the ng-click event. Change sumit() to submit().

:)